# Ignore git file's changes in all repositories keeping it in repository

Tags: git

I have a file in a git repository, I have done previously commits in the file but from today I want any changes on the file is ignored in ALL repositories but keeping the file in the repository.

I have tested with `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` but it only ignores the file's local changes (I need the file to be ignored in ALL repositories).

I have tested with `git git rm --cached <file>` but it removes the file in another repositories when I synch my repository with another repositories (I need to keep it in all repositories).

Comment: add it to .gitignore?

Comment: What you mean by `ALL repositories`? Can give a example of what you are trying to achieve, that involve more than one repo?

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm afraid you can't do that. `git rm --cached` won't work for obvious reasons and you can't `update-index` on other local repositories. I guess pre-receive hook on remote repository that rejects any push attempts that contain specific file would do the trick. On hooks read more [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)